# Why expression is always true for 'double-checked-locking'?

Tags: c#, singleton, resharper

I have singleton object 'Service' and two methods to initialize and release it:

```
public class BaseService
{
    protected static readonly object StaticLockObject = new object();
}

public abstract class WebServiceBase<TService> : BaseService
    where TService : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol, new()
{
    protected static void EnsureServiceIsOpened()
    {
        if (Service == null)
        {
            lock (StaticLockObject)
            {
                if (Service == null)
                {
                    Service = new TService();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected static void EnsureServiceIsClosed()
    {
        if (Service != null)
        {
            lock (StaticLockObject)
            {
                if (Service != null) // Why expression is always true
                {
                    Service.Dispose();
                    Service = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For the line with comment resharper (I use version 5.1) displays a mentioned warning...

**Question 1:** Why?

**Question 2:** Why it doesn't display "similar" message in 'EnsureServiceIsOpened' method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is bug in ReSharper 5.X code analysis engine.
Fixed in ReSharper 6.0.

BTW, ReSharper 6 brings more double-lock pattern analysis stuff :)

Answer (score 4):

Resharper does a limited analysis of the code, and sees the two nested `if` statements checking exactly the same. In a single threaded environment, the comment by resharper holds perfectly true - there is no way `Service` will be `null` after the first `if`. In a multithreaded envrionment of course, this doesn't apply, as `Service` could be changed from the outside. This is a case where you should annotate the code for resharper or surpress the message for this file, as it doesn't hold true in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: It's won't break your code a single threaded app - why this a *warning* puzzles me. :/

Comment: Because it might happen. Code analysis can only go so far - and that's why this warning appears.

Comment: I don't have a problem with this being shown by Resharper, I don't think it should be a warning. :)

Answer (score 3):

It appears that Resharper is making a mistake in this analysis. Since `Service` is not a local variable, it cannot know that that expression will always be true.

The reason why the error doesn't show up for the first version is likely because the double-checked-lock idiom is so common, and that is its usual form. They probably tested for that case and removed the erroneous warning.

The technique displayed in `EnsureServiceIsClosed` is not common because it contains a race condition. Another thread could be using the object indicated by `Service` while—or after—it is being disposed. This would not be possible if the code that uses the Service locks on `StaticLockObject`, but if it does take the lock, then there is no reason to do all this double-checked locking rigamarole around creating and disposing the object. Therefore, it is virutally certain that this code is flawed.